# Add event listener to document opened in new window

Tags: javascript, event-handling, dom-events, visibility

Is there anything that prevents me from adding a event listener to the window that results from a `window.open()` call?

I am trying to set a handler function to be triggered on a visibility change event on the new document, but this handler function is not being called.

Comment: Is the document you are opening with `window.open()` the same origin (e.g. same domain, port and protocol) as the one you are opening it from?  If not, then the browser restricts what you can do with a cross origin document, including the installation of event handlers.

Answer (score 7):

There's nothing that prevents you from doing that (*as long as the window you are opening is in the same domain as the parent/opener window; Just imagine what malicious people could do if that weren't the case*). 
Once you have the `window` object of that new window, then you can do whatever you want to it. `window.open()` returns the `window` object of the new window:

```
// * All of this code is happening inside of the parent window,
// * but you can also 'inject' scripts into the new window if you wish.

// window.open() returns the new window's window object
var newWin = window.open('http://stackoverflow.com');
// Run all of your code onload, so you can manipulate the 
// new window's DOM. Else, you're just manipulating an empty doc.
newWin.onload = function () {
    // `this`, in this context, makes reference to the new window object
    // You can use DOM methods, on the new document, with it.
    var myElem = this.document.getElementById('custom-header');
    console.log("Window object: ", this);
    console.log("Window's location: ", this.location.href);
    console.log("Id of element in new window: ", myElem.id);
    // Attach a click event to the new document's body
    this.document.body.onclick = function () {
        // `this`, inside of a listener, is the element itself
        // but this console.log will log inside of the parent window
        console.log(this);
        this.style.transition = 'all 1s';
        this.style.opacity = 0;
    };
    this.document.body.addEventListener('click', function () {
        // Now, let's log inside of the new window.
        // Since in here, this === this.document.body,
        // then you'll have to use the newWin var we set before.
        // newWin is the window object.
        newWin.console.log('Logging in new window!');
    });
};
```

Comment: That new `window` object is still subject to same-origin restrictions, so if it isn't the same domain, then your first sentence in your answer is incorrect.

Comment: Oh yeah, I just assumed we were talking about a window opened from the same domain. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: It's not in the same domain. So can I assume that would explain why it is not working?

Comment: Yeah, and as far as I know, there's no way to circumvent that limitation... especially if you have no control over the other domain. I guess this answer is not so useful then, so I'll get rid of it in a bit, if there are no further comments. : p

Comment: Oh, don't get rid of it, please!
It might be helpful for someone in another situation! Thank you for your help, anyway :)

Comment: not working for me