# Detect when a new tab is fully loaded after opening it

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am opening a new tab link with an  element.
var w = window.open(`mailto:example@gmail.com ...`, '_blank');

After that I check for when it finishes loading:

```
if (w != null) {
  console.log("here");

  $(w).on('load',function () {
    console.log("here2");
  }
}
```

However, I never get "here2" printed, even long after the tab finished loading.

Notes:

I have also tried opening youtube, still here2 wasn't printed.

I tried opening the localhost link (I am runnning this on a localhost test server), and it can detect when my same site finished loading.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30040441/javascript-add-event-listener-to-document-opened-in-new-window) if the site you want to open is on the same domain as your website.

On the other side, there is nearly no hope if there is a site that does not have the same-origin content, since you will get the [same-origin](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy/) error.

If you have permission to add code to a "no same-origin" site (B) then you can send a signal to your original site (A) in some way (e.g. send a signal from B to the server and then send the signal return to A).